# Is this Markov Chain positive recurrent?

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes

I have an exam on stochastic processes tomorrow and now a quick question on how to prove positive recurrence.

Given a random walk on $\mathbb{Z}$ corresponding to the transition matrix
$$P(k,k)=\frac{1}{2},~P(k,k+1)=P(k,k-1)=\frac{1}{4}.$$
This defines an irreducible, aperiodic and recurrent Markov chain. Hence, we have one unique invariant measure. I could show that this verifies 
$$\mu(k)=(\mu(1)-\mu(0))\cdot k+\mu(0)=:A\cdot k+B.$$
Is it correct to now say the sum
$$\sum_{k\in\mathbb{Z}}\mu(k)=\sum_{k\in\mathbb{Z}}A\cdot k+B$$
diverges (therefore $\mu$ does not define a probability measure) to justify that the Markov chain is not positive recurrent?

Comment: Actually there are many invariant measures. And yes you showed that none of them is a probability measure hence the chain is null recurrent.

Comment: Thank you, that is good! Am I correct though in assuming that all the measures are multiples of each other?

Comment: Yes. $ $ $ $ $ $